# How do you know on NUnit TearDown if a test threw an exception and what that exception was?

Tags: nunit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In the teardown event during an NUnit test how can I get to the attribute applied to the method that was just tested?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762278/in-the-teardown-event-during-an-nunit-test-how-can-i-get-to-the-attribute-applie)

I have an bunch of NUnit tests that all inherit from a class that implements the NUnit Teardown function.

[TearDown]
        public void TeardownTest() { }

Whenever one of the tests generate an exception it just jumps straight to the TearDown function. How do I know what the exception was that was generated that caused it to go to that exception?

Answer (score 0):

This has been already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762278/in-the-teardown-event-during-an-nunit-test-how-can-i-get-to-the-attribute-applied).